# Show that for all complex number $z \not= -1$ and $|z|=1$ can be written as a form : $z= \frac{1+it}{1-it}$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that for all complex number $z \not= -1$ and $|z|=1$ can be written as a form: $$z= \frac{1+it}{1-it},\quad t \in \mathbb{R}$$.

I succeed to prove this problem with stereographic projection with central point $(-1,0)$.

Why it doesn't work with $|z|=r \not= 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

$$z = \frac{1-it}{1+it}$$ with real $t$, then

$$|z| =\frac{|1+it|}{|1-it|}= \frac{1+t^2}{1+(-t)^2} =1$$ so any such $z$ is on the unit circle.

Comment: @simons Please read the OP's actual question!

Comment: @SimonS The question (not the title, though) is “Why it doesn't work with $|z|=r≠1$?” and the OP says he/she was able to do the first part.

Comment: @egreg precisely. thank you

Comment: I edited your question in order to allow the downvoter to retract the vote. I like it, because it's straight to the point.

Comment: @egreg I apprecaite that!

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve the equation:
$$
(1-it)z=1+it
$$
that gives
$$
it(1+z)=1-z
$$
that is,
$$
t=i\frac{z-1}{z+1}
$$
which shows $z\ne-1$ is necessary.

The condition $t$ is real is
$$
i\frac{z-1}{z+1}=-i\frac{\bar{z}-1}{\bar{z}+1}
$$
that can be rewritten
$$
z\bar{z}+z-\bar{z}-1=-z\bar{z}-\bar{z}+z+1
$$
that is
$$
z\bar{z}=1
$$

Comment: Am i correct in saying that you showed that if $|z|=1$ then $z = \frac{1+it}{1-it}$ for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$ but have not necessarily shown the converse?

Comment: @NobelCat You can do the steps in the reverse order. In other words each step is linked to the following one by “if and only if”.